# d3js g element x is NaN

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using d3js, this is my code:

```
function update () {
    var _node = vis.select("#nodeG").selectAll("g.node")
                   .data(nodes, function (d) {
                       return d.id; 
                   });

    var n = _node.enter().append("g")
                 .attr("class", "node")
                 .call(force.drag);

    n.append("svg:a").attr("xlink:href", function (d) { return "/user/" + d.id; })
            .append("svg:circle")
            .attr("class", "nodeCircle")
            .attr("cx", function () {
                i++
                return parseFloat((i * 50) + 25);
            })
            .attr("cy", HEIGHT / 2)
            .attr("r", function (d) { return d.r; });

    force.on("tick", function () {
    _node.attr("transform", function (d) {
         return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
     });
});
```

The problem is that `d.x` and `d.y` gives me a `NaN`. I have no idea why. Can someone help me please.

Comment: I'm assuming that you're using the force layout. Have you assigned the `nodes` data and started it?

Comment: Thanks! That was it. I had the start() method but on the wrong position. Another question: can I use the tick method without the d3 force?

Comment: Well you'll need something to generate the `tick` event.

Comment: Can you give me an example? I have nodes and links between some nodes and want to update them on drag. But I don't need the functionality of the force layout.

Comment: Use the [drag behavior](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Drag-Behavior) for that.

Comment: Than I have to implement the positions and so on like in the force layout, right?

Comment: You have to set the initial positions yourself, yes.

Comment: No, I mean the x, y positions (what the force layout is using) in the elements.

Comment: If you don't use the force layout, you have to set the positions yourself.